# Purple rinse water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, water

After forming a white substance while on the stove, I rinsed the Pyrex pot under tap water (from a well), whereupon the water in the pot turned purple. Why did this happen?

Iron and sulfur are present in the well water here.

Revision: I had prepared white tea in a white corning pot on the stove. After pouring out the tea I rinsed the pot with the tap water (well water) which turned a purplish color and then clear.

Comment: @airhuff Please remember to check for tags if you are editing a question’s grammar, wording and/or title. See for example [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2940) or [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2967).

Comment: First of all, welcome to Chemistry.SE! I suggest that you start off by taking the [tour] to learn more about how this site works. Regarding your question, could you give a little more information?  What was in the pot?  Where was the white stuff, etc.?

Comment: What were you cooking that formed the white substance? There could be some residue that caused it.

Comment: Does it stay purple or change to red, brown, yellow, clear, etc. after a while?